# Filling up a Time Series DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have imported a DataFrame with time series data using Pandas. The first column is an incomplete DatTimevector, as the Time Series data only includes data point where there a trade was made. In the next four are prices, and in the last three columns 'Trade Volume', 'Number of Ticks' and 'Value'.  I want to edit this DataFrame in the following way: I want the date vector to be filled up, such that the timestep is a constant 1 minute, and for all the inserted rows I want the last three columns to be zero. I did this with the following code.

```
def insert_row(idx, df, df_insert):
    dfA = df.iloc[:idx, ]
    dfB = df.iloc[idx:, ]

    df = dfA.append(df_insert).append(dfB).reset_index(drop = True)

    return df

df=pd.read_excel("file_location",skiprows=3,sheet_name='sheet1')
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    while df.iloc[i,0]-df.iloc[i-1,0]>pd.Timedelta('1 minute'):
        df=insert_row(i,df,df.iloc[i-1]+[pd.Timedelta('1minute'),
                0,0,0,0,-df.iloc[i-1,-3],-df.iloc[i-1,-2],-df.iloc[i-,-1]])
```

Does anyone have another way to do this that is nicer and more efficient?

The data looks as following:

[Time Series Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY5iI.png)

The desired output would be:
[Desired output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqp1I.png)

```
{'Close': {0: 12.65, 1: 12.65, 2: 12.65, 3: 12.65, 4: 12.65},

'Dates': {0: Timestamp('2018-01-08 09:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2018-01-08 09:01:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2018-01-08 09:05:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2018-01-08 09:06:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2018-01-08 09:10:00')},

'High': {0: 12.65, 1: 12.65, 2: 12.65, 3: 12.65, 4: 12.65},

'Low': {0: 12.6, 1: 12.65, 2: 12.65, 3: 12.65, 4: 12.65},

'Number_Ticks': {0: 16, 1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1},

'Open': {0: 12.6, 1: 12.65, 2: 12.65, 3: 12.65, 4: 12.65},

'Value': {0: 83071.8438,
  1: 17279.8984,
  2: 12839.75,
  3: 4263.0498,
  4: 4288.3501},

'Volume': {0: 6568, 1: 1366, 2: 1015, 3: 337, 4: 339}}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please paste `df.head().to_dict()` so we can see your data. Also have a read through [mcve] and update your question, as this will help you get more responses going forward.

Comment: If that code is copy-pasted, i should raise errors. `,sheet_name='sheet1)` is missing the closing `'`

Comment: Where is your reproducible *input* data [as text, not pictures].

Comment: df.head().to_dict() gives the bottom part of my question, is that what you mean?

Comment: Please paste the sample data and wanted info as a `csv` instead of a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Using `resample` and `fillna` this should be rather easy

```
df2 = df.set_index('Dates').resample('1 min').first()
price_df = df2[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', ]].fillna(method='bfill')
volume_df = df2[['Volume', 'Number_Ticks', 'Value',]].fillna(0)
result = pd.concat((price_df, volume_df), axis=1)
```

> ```
>   Open    High    Low     Close   Volume  Number_Ticks    Value
> Dates                             
> 2018-01-08 09:00:00   12.60   12.65   12.60   12.65   6568.0  16.0    83071.8438
> 2018-01-08 09:01:00   12.65   12.65   12.65   12.65   1366.0  4.0     17279.8984
> 2018-01-08 09:02:00   12.65   12.65   12.65   12.65   0.0     0.0     0.0000
> 2018-01-08 09:03:00   12.65   12.65   12.65   12.65   0.0     0.0     0.0000
> 2018-01-08 09:04:00   12.65   12.65   12.65   12.65   0.0     0.0     0.0000
> 2018-01-08 09:05:00   12.65   12.65   12.65   12.65   1015.0  3.0     12839.7500
> 2018-01-08 09:06:00   12.65   12.65   12.65   12.65   337.0   1.0     4263.0498
> 2018-01-08 09:07:00   12.65   12.65   12.65   12.65   0.0     0.0     0.0000
> 2018-01-08 09:08:00   12.65   12.65   12.65   12.65   0.0     0.0     0.0000
> 2018-01-08 09:09:00   12.65   12.65   12.65   12.65   0.0     0.0     0.0000
> 2018-01-08 09:10:00   12.65   12.65   12.65   12.65   339.0   1.0     4288.3501
> ```